# How to use the regroup tag in Django

Tags: django

I have the same structure that the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) suggests but it doesn't print me

```
<li>None
 <ul>
  <li>: </li>
  <li>: </li>
  <li>: </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

prints as 920 blank items, here is my structure

`[{'where': 'Mumbai', 'attribute': 'title', 'error': 'India'}, {'where': 'Calcutta', 'attribute': 'nameFile', 'error': 'India '}, {' where ':' New York ',' attribute ':' sizeFile ',' error ':' USA '}, {' where ':' New York ',' attribute ':' amount_stars ',' error ': '12'}, {'where': 'Chicago', 'attribute': 'subject', 'error': 'USA'}, {'where': 'Tokyo', 'attribute': 'nameGrade', 'error': 'Japan'}, {'where': 'Mumbai', 'attribute': 'nameLevel', 'error': 'Level One'}, {'where': 'Mumbai', 'attribute': ' amount_stars', 'error': '1'}]`

try to make it the same with the difference that I want to **group by where**

```html
{% regroup list_errorsProcess by where as where_list%}
<ul>
{% for where in where_list%}
                            <li> {{where.grouper}}
                                <ul>
                                    {% for err in where.list%}
                                    <li> {{err.attribute}}: {{err.error}} </li>
                                    {% endfor%}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor%}
                    </ul>
```

suddenly something you forget (maybe you don't care about something in the view or ...)

also I need to check the number of elements but tag | length tells me that there are 462 and not the 8 .count tag instead nothing, thanks any suggestion

expected result

```html
<ul>
    <li>Mumbai
        <ul>
            <li>title: India</li>
            <li>nameLevel: Level One</li>
            <li>amount_stars: 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Calcutta
        <ul>
            <li>nameFile: India</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>New York
        <ul>
            <li>sizeFile: USA</li>
            <li>amount_stars: 12</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Chicago
        <ul>
            <li>subject: USA</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Tokyo
        <ul>
            <li>nameGrade: Japan</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ```{% regroup downloads.errorsProcess by donde as donde_list %}
                    <ul>
                    {% for donde, local_errores in donde_list %}
                        <li>{{ donde }}
                        <ul>
                            {% for campo in local_errores %}
                            <li>{{ campo.atributo }}: {{ campo.error }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have name conflicts, try to change `where` to `group`

```
{% regroup list_errorsProcess by where as where_list %}

<ul>
    {% for group in where_list %}
        <li> {{ group.grouper}}
            <ul>
                {% for err in group.list %}
                <li> {{err.attribute}}: {{err.error}} </li>
                {% endfor%}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor%}
</ul>
```